# Angular 2 not loading in IE 11 even after making all the changes mentioned in previous stackflow questions as well as GitHub and other websites

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-services, typescript2.0

We are working on Angular 2 and are able to load everything on all web browsers except IE 11 (and below). The complete typescript itself is not getting loaded and there is nothing on the console to analyze. We tried the following but they did not solve our problem. We used Angular 2 dot net core under webpack. Please suggest me other options and recommendations that worked for you....

1. < meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
2. Uncommented the polyfills in polyfills.ts file in src folder
3. In tsconfig.json file changed target to es5

Comment: This is what I have..
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

Comment: Hi We tried using that as well but it isn't working...are you aware of any other changes or additions we need to make...please let me know.....

Comment: That's strange. I would recommend creating a new angular project and see if it works on IE. If it does then you know that you're missing something on this project. If it doesn't then you know that it is something else preventing it to work on IE.

Comment: Yes we were thinking of the same :) We will try that and update our results here again...Thank u

Comment: niraja k, have you tried what jriver27 suggested as is, all lower-case? this related issue https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1656 says that http-equiv and content in IE are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes Flavio Cysne tried in all cases....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved up in the version to handle this